# Solving the integro-differential equation (Cauchy problem) using Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, integro-differential-equations

I am stuck trying to solve this equation using Laplace transform:

> $$ y''(t)+2y(t)=\displaystyle 3\int_0^t (t−u)y(u)du\\ y(0)=2 , y'(0)=3 $$

I got stuck after performing the Laplace transformation and can't get the equation to a form I can do the inverse Laplace transformation on.

Here's what I got:
$$p^2Y(p)- py(0)-y'(0) + 2Y(p) = 3/p^2 * Y(p) $$ which then simplifies to: $$ Y(p) = (2p+3)/(p^2-3/p^2 +2)$$

**How can I do inverse Laplace on this?**

Thank you

Comment: $$\frac{\left(3+2 p\right) p^{2}}{p^{4}+2 p^{2}-3}=-\frac{1}{8 \left(p+1\right)}+\frac{5}{8 \left(p-1\right)}+\frac{9+6 p}{4 \left(p^{2}+3\right)}$$

Comment: Is the upper limit of integration $3$ or $t$? If it is $3$, then it is useless to invert $Y(p)$, as the Laplace transform of $\int_0^3(t-u)y(u)du$ is not $Y(p)/p^2$.

Comment: the upper limit is t